# Need help setting up an asyncio loop that edits my message over a set interval of time, for making a timer countdown command for my discord.py bot

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to edit the `int(time)` value sent by the user and keep editing it over a loop until it reaches 0. Here's my current code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def settimer(ctx, time: int):

        await ctx.send('Timer set for ' + str(time) + ' seconds')

        if int(time) > 10:
            await asyncio.sleep(time)

            message = await ctx.send(str(time))
            while int(time) > 0:

                while int(newtime) > 0:
                        await asyncio.sleep(4)
                        newtime = int(time) - 4
                        await message.edit(content = str(newtime))
                        newtime = newtime - 4
                        await asyncio.sleep(4)


        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(time)
            await ctx.send('Timer Over! ' + ctx.message.author.mention)
            print ('time was less than 10')
```

Comment: If you are editing this every second, you will be rate limited by the api, as an edit every second is a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop will infinitely loop since `time` never changes. The inner loop will also infinitely loop when time is > 8, since `newtime` is set to `time` in every iteration of the loop.

Also, you're sleeping 4 seconds twice in between each message edit after the first.

Additionally, the entire method is improperly indented twice, and the code inside the inner loop is improperly indented twice as well.

I'm not sure if this is intended, but you're also sleeping `time` seconds before the timer message is even sent.

`time` should already be an `int`, so there's no reason to cast it to `int` again.

You can simply use a single loop and decrement the single variable with a single sleep, e.g.:

```py
            while time > 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(4)
                time -= 4
                await message.edit(content = str(time))
```

For `-=`, see [Python's documentation on augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements).

You might also want to look into [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Also, these are normal `while` loops, not "asyncio loop"s, which generally refer to [event loops](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html).